# Analysis for evolution of resistance

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, t-test, panel-data, model

I am looking for help on an approach for analyzing evolution of resistance.
I conducted an experiment in which I exposed pathogens to a constant drug concentration over 6 weeks. At each week, I tested drug resistance in the exposed lines, and also in control lines that were propagated in the absence of the drug. I have three replicate sub-cultured lines within each treatment (n=3).

Here's a link to the DATA and my SCRIPT

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1YU9mSCw_jSbnpXVkYyWHJoTG8
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1YU9mSCw_jSb0MzZzZvMEtVYmM

[![Figure of ec50 ratios over time][3]][3]
I was planning to analyze this with a mixed model (lmer) of:
**Drug EC50 ~ Treatment*Time + (1|Line)**
to account for repeated measures on the lines in each week.

However, the effect of time on EC50 is not at all linear. 
So my next idea was to standardize each week's EC50 values relative to the average EC50 in the control lines in the same week. So the model looks like:
lmer(**standardized ec50 ~ Treatment*Time + (1|Line)**)
However, this seems to cause problems with the likelihood ratio test for the effect of time, because there is no variation in the control group: the standardized ec50 is pinned at 1.00 for each week.
With this model, I get a df=0 when I compare full and reduced models, and p-values that are either 0 or 1. I feel like something is being divided by zero.
I can still do chi-squared tests, but I preferred to use likelihood ratio tests, and I'm a little worried about the model because the likelihood ratio tests aren't behaving normally.

My third idea was just to abandon the mixed model framework in favor of Tukey-corrected 
**t-tests of exposed vs. control lines ... at each timepoint**
This would avoid the problem of explicitly testing the effect of time, and also avoid pretending that there was a linear effect of time.
However, I'm concerned about just having n=3 at each timepoint, and also not having an overarching model for the whole analysis.

What analysis is best?
Analysis on absolute ec50 values or ratios?
Mixed-effects model or t-tests?